# how to decode long int to its string value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Any data, string/long/dobule or in saved in memory as hex or decimal values.

Based on my point, **I want to get the double value of the string** and sent it over transmission and **decode the received double value to string**.

In C, I can get following working.

## TX

```
char name[6] = "me123"//underline decimal value is 2127182692
send((double)(long)name);
```

## RX

```
double rx_val = receive();
char *new_string = (char*)(long)rx_val ;
printf("the string %s \n", new_string );
```

I could not succeed with RX with python3.

tried with following

[image]

got error

[image]

how to get double value to string decoding get working?

Comment: You want `encode`, not `decode`.

Comment: P.S. your C code makes no sense either.  I have no idea how you're coming up with a value of 2127182692.

Comment: the value is probably the pointer value (memory address), if that code was actually used. - although even them, printed as "long", not as "double".

Comment: You both are right, thanks for pointing out the bug

Comment: correct value is 2130705428

Answer (score 3):

Ordinary strings in Python represent Unicode objects - and they have to be converted *first* to a concrete bytes representation by an specific codec using the `.encode(...)` method. By default, `utf-8` is used, but any encoding can be used, and it is necessary if the text you get goes outside the ASCII correspondence to Unicode codepoints- (32-127) .

That done, the `int` class in Python has a convenient "from_bytes" method that can combine how many bytes you want into a single numeric value.

In short:

```
mytext = "me123"
mybytes = mytext.encode("utf-8")
mynumber = int.from_bytes(mybytes, "little")
print(mynumber)
```

Now, if you want the bytes to be seem as a C double (float64), then you can, instead, just decode each 8 bytes as double using the `struct` module. Note however, that you are responsible to padding the bytes-string to 8 bytes
(you are also responsible for that in C, you did not do it, and may have encoded garbage and did risk a segmentation fault, anyway)

```
mytext = "me123"
mybytes = mytext.encode("utf-8")
mybytes += b"\x00" * (8 - len(mybytes) % 8) + mybytes
from struct import unpack
mydouble = unpack("<d", mybytes[:8])[0]
print(mydouble)
```

However, I could not match the numeric value you posted in the question body, neither as integers nor as float64s- probably due to the extra 2 garbage bytes involved in your snippets.

Rather, actually if your C code is at it shows up in the question, the value you are displaing as "double" is actually the transient memory address where your data actually is - as a char[] variable in C is a pointer, not holder of the actual contents, even if declaring a variable as char[6] allocates statically the needed memory. If you do use (double)(*my_text) in your C code (and do the proper 0 padding) you will find the same values as in Python.

**to sum up** It is likely that your actual problem only needs you to deal with byte-strings (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) in Python, and no fancy numeric conversions at all - unless you are getting actual structured binary data from the other endpoint, in which case you should just use the struct module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to get your actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me up to 6 bytes. I am still having issues coping over 6 bytes here.

**c**

```
   char temp_id[8] = "smg123";
    char dbl_to_str[8];
    uint64_t id = 0;
    memcpy(&id, temp_id, 8);
    memcpy(dbl_to_str, &id, 8);
    printf("Double to String %s\n", dbl_to_str);
```

**python**

print(message.data, data)

printed
[image: printed print(message.data, data)]